# What is the difference enctype="multipart/form-data" and enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8"

Tags: php, html

I have experienced turkish character issue with form post,

I'm experiencing issue when I try the code below,

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// some input
</form>
```

But it's working fine when I try this

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8">
// some input
</form>
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: What issue are you experiencing? Show a real examoke,  It appears to be an odd issue, if using an invalid enctype “fixes” it (the `multipart/form-data` type does not allow a `charset` parameter; my guess is that it “works” because the attribute is *ignored*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you are using whatever the pages default charset is, which probably the ISO-8859-1 charset which doesn't have the extended characters.  By forcing it into UTF-8 you get the additional characters.  See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp for more information.